# Why can I use :: operator with Seq in pattern matching but not elsewhere

Tags: scala

So I have been really confused with this behavior regarding Seq in Scala.

When using pattern matching I am able to use either `::` or `+:` operator and they seem interchangeable

```
val s=Seq(1,2,3)
s match{
case x :: l => ...
```

but when I'm trying to use `::` in different situation like so:

```
val s=1::Seq(2,3)
```

I receive `"value :: is not a member of Seq[Int]"` message. I understand that I am supposed to use `+=` and `=+` operators with Seq, but why 
`::` work only in pattern matching scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`::` is for `List`s, and in fact `Seq.apply` will currently give you a `List`:

```
scala> val s = Seq(1,2,3)
s: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

So the type of value `s` is `Seq[Int]`, but the object it points to is of type `List[Int]`.  That's fine, because `List` extends `Seq`.  And that will of course match a pattern involving `::` because it is in fact a `List`:

```
scala> s match { case x :: xs => x }
res2: Int = 1
```

But the type of expression `Seq(1,2,3)` is not `List[Int]` but `Seq[Int]` -- even though the actual object is indeed a `List`. So the following fails because `Seq` does not define a `::` method:

```
scala> val s = 1 :: Seq(2,3)
<console>:7: error: value :: is not a member of Seq[Int]
       val s = 1 :: Seq(2,3)
```

You have to use the method for `Seq` instead:

```
scala> val s = 1 +: Seq(2,3)
s: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

The key to your confusion is that when you invoke a method on a value like `s`, the set of methods available depends entirely on the value's *static* type, whereas the pattern match checks that the object being matched is of class `::`.

To show this, let's compile some sample code and use `javap` to see the bytecode; the first few instructions of the `first` method check that the argument is of class `::` (rather than some other class extending `Seq`) and cast to it:

```
NS% cat Test.scala
object Test {
  def first(xs: Seq[Int]) = xs match { case x :: xs => x }
}

NS% javap -c Test\$.class
Compiled from "Test.scala"
public final class Test$ {
  public static final Test$ MODULE$;

  public static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Test$
       3: invokespecial #12                 // Method "<init>":()V
       6: return

  public int first(scala.collection.Seq<java.lang.Object>);
    Code:
       0: aload_1
       1: astore_2
       2: aload_2
       3: instanceof    #16                 // class scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon
       6: ifeq          30
       9: aload_2
      10: checkcast     #16                 // class scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon
      13: astore_3
      14: aload_3
      15: invokevirtual #20                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon.head:()Ljava/lang/Object;
      18: invokestatic  #26                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
      21: istore        4
      23: iload         4
      25: istore        5
      27: iload         5
      29: ireturn
      30: new           #28                 // class scala/MatchError
      33: dup
      34: aload_2
      35: invokespecial #31                 // Method scala/MatchError."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      38: athrow
```

Finally, you could ask why the Scala folks didn't make `::` the equivalent method (prepend an element) for `Seq`.  If they had, then `1 :: Seq(2,3)` would work.

But for `Seq` they really needed a *pair* of operators, one to prepend (this one must end in a colon, so that it is right-associative) and one to append.  You want to avoid appending an element to a `List` because you have to traverse the existing elements to do so, but the same is not true for `Seq`s in general -- e.g. append is quite efficient for a `Vector`.  So they chose `+:` for prepend and `:+` for append.

Of course, you could ask why they didn't use `+:` for `List` to match `Seq`.  I don't know the full answer to that.  I do know that `::` comes from other languages which have list structures, so in part the answer is probably consistency with established conventions.  And perhaps they did not realize that they wanted a matching pair of operators for a supertype of `List` until it was too late -- not sure.  Does anyone know the history here?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my imprecise language, m-z; I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

`::` pronounced [cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Cons) is an operator for [Lists](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List). 
[Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.Seq) is a generic trait that all Scala sequences inherit. This is a generic interface for any type of sequence and not just for lists.

Given that the by default Scala uses `Lists` as the sequence return by the `Seq()` factory method, then Pattern Matching can operate with cons.

So you can do

```
val s = 1::List(2,3)
```

But not

```
val s = 1::Seq(2,3)
```