# Scala List method `::` vs `+:`

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Can't see the real difference between `::` and `+:` method of Scala List.

I used REPL to test and can't see diff from the result.

Anyone can give me how can I use that properly?

Comment: :: is not defined for Seq, only for List

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959597/why-can-i-use-operator-with-seq-in-pattern-matching-but-not-elsewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the code of [List](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala), `+:` uses `::` (cons) operator for prepending.

```
override def +:[B >: A, That](elem: B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That = bf match {
  case _: List.GenericCanBuildFrom[_] => (elem :: this).asInstanceOf[That]
  case _ => super.+:(elem)(bf)
}
```

In general, `+:` is defined in `SeqLike` and any collection implementing `SeqLike` can use the same.

On the other hand `::` is defined in `List` and can only be used by `List`.

Comment: So for a list, i can use both +: and ::? Interchangeable?